# PHP DOM Cannot get a hyperlink value from a tag element

Tags: php, dom

I am trying to get the hyperlink from a 'a' tag. I am using the php_simple_html_dom library. Here is a screenshot:

[image]

I am trying to get the value of the attribute `href` which is: "/HERSHEYS-105ct-Assorted-Valentines-Chocolate/dp/B07VJJVKXL/ref=sr_1_1?keywords=B07VJJVKXL&qid=1579006135&smid=A3DWYIK6Y9EEQB&sr=8-1" by finding its class name. However when I debug the variable below, it always throws a null value. Here is my code:

```
$firstEntry = $dom->find(".a-link-normal a-text-normal", 0);
        //var_dump($firstEntry);
        if(isset($firstEntry)){

            $firstEntryLink = $firstEntry->href;
            var_dump($firstEntryLink);
            if(isset($firstEntryLink)){

                $res=getWebPage($firstEntryLink);
                //var_dump($res);
            } 

        }
```

I tried with the other classes but the case was the same.

Comment: Right now, you are trying to find an element with the _tag name_ `a-text-normal` _inside_ of an element with the class `a-link-normal` - but there is none. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Class_selectors for an example how selecting an element based on multiple classes actually works.

Comment: It is actually the same syntax but I think the class name which has to be the right one is different or it is one of the parent once in the DOM tree

Comment: _“It is actually the same syntax”_ - no, it is not.

Comment: `$firstEntry = $dom->find("a.a-link-normal.a-text-normal", 0);` - This is the right syntax. Thank you for your help and for the useful web page you gave!